# Difference in time is giving Invalid date

Tags: javascript, asp.net, time

I have a scenario, where I want to show the total time of employee after calculating the `InTime` and `OutTime` from the first two textboxes.

Here Is the scenario,

`In first textbox` User will add `INTIME`

`In Second textbox` User will add `OUTTIME`.

As soon as both the values are entered, the third textbox will show the total time the employee has worked.

Here is what I tried.

HTML

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblInTime" runat="server" Text="In Time" Visible="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInTime" runat="server" Width="89px"></asp:TextBox> (HH:MM)
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regIntime" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtInTime"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter time in correct format" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblOutTime" runat="server" Text="Out Time" Visible="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOutTime" runat="server" onkeyup="sum();" Width="89"> 
                </asp:TextBox> (HH:MM) 
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regOuttime" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtOutTime"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter time in correct format" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotalHr" runat="server" Text="Total Hours" Visible="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalHrs" runat="server" Width="70" ReadOnly="true" onkeyUp="TimeCalculation();">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function TimeCalculation() {
       var start = $('#txtInTime').val();
       var end = $('#txtOutTime').val();
       var diff = new Date(end - start);
       $('#txtTotalHrs').val(diff);
   }
```

But the issue is that, I am getting error in thid textbox as

> Invalid Date.

**Note** My date format is HH:MM and in 24 hrs format

Kindly suggest where I am mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To subtract start from end, you have to convert both of them to dates first.

Change your JavaScript function:

```
function TimeCalculation() 
    var start = $('#txtInTime').val();
    var startHours = parseInt(start.split(":")[0]);
    var startMins = parseInt(start.split(":")[1]); 

    var end = $('#txtOutTime').val();
    var endHours = parseInt(end.split(":")[0]); 
    var endMins = parseInt(end.split(":")[1]); 

    var diffHours = endHours - startHours;
    var diffMins = endMins - startMins;
    diffHours = ("0" + diffHours).slice(-2);
    diffMins = ("0" + diffMins).slice(-2); 
    var diff = diffHours + ":" + diffMins;
    $('#txtTotalHrs').val(diff); 

}
```

Comment: I am getting total as `Thu Jan 01` :(

Comment: @nadeem Sorry, are you trying to get the total or the difference?

Comment: I want the difference,  `2ndTextbox` - `1st Textbox` and result should be in `3rdTextbox`

Comment: @nadeem Then why d you need to get the total? I'm confused.

Comment: I m sorry that's not necessary, just want to show the difference in the third textbox

Comment: no, It is giving result what I showed in my first comment

Comment: @nadeem What is your expected output? Check out my edit by the way.

Comment: See, if first text box value is `10:00` and second textbox `18:40` so the time difference should be `08:40`

Comment: @nadeem Right, give me some time. By the way, you don't need dates to do this.

Comment: Sure, take your time. Also, It's time not the date. Like in a company where InTime and OutTime is calculated

Comment: Do I have to write anything on Total Textbox like `onKeyUp` or something like that

Comment: @nadeem Are you referring to this? `<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalHrs" runat="server" Width="70" ReadOnly="true" onkeyUp="TimeCalculation();">
                </asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Yes, this is my textbox where I will show the result

Comment: I dont think so. Instead you should add it to the `onkeyup` for the two other textboxes. But the problem is you have to finish typing both of those textboxes before the total textbox works properly. So instead you might want to use a button and when clicked, execute the `TimeCalculation()` function.

Comment: Actually right now I m not using button, So can you help me where exactly i should use these function. Please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80149/discussion-between-chris97ong-and-nadeem).